# How do I retrieve a customer's details from Stripe using an identifier, such as their email?

Tags: api, next.js, stripe-payments, stripe-customers

I'm using Stripe in a React demo site.

I'm looking to retrieve customer details and display them on-screen, ahead of adding basic authentication to an area - think "account area of e-commerce site", but very basic!

The problem I have is that while I can create an instance of Stripe, I'm getting zero data back in the response - here is the code I have:

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(
  <MY SK_TEST... ID>
);

const customers = await stripe.customers.list({
  email: "alex.test@outlook.com",
});

console.log("CUSTOMERS", JSON.stringify(customers));
```

This is in a basic React page - I'm using it to trigger retrieving the data each time I refresh the page. The response I get back is this:

`CUSTOMERS {"object":"list","data":[],"has_more":false,"url":"/v1/customers"}`

My Stripe set up is running in test mode at present - should this cause an issue? I have a customer listed in the Customers section of my Stripe dashboard, so I should have at least one response back.

I've also checked multiple pages in SO which show similar calls to retrieve customer detail, so I'm reasonably sure that the `const customers...` is good; not sure why it's returning nothing! I have also tried adding the backend API route from https://stackoverflow.com/a/74669051/9851653, and added this as the POST:

```
// api/get-all-customers.js

import Stripe from "stripe";
export default async function handler(req, res) {
if (req.method === "POST") {
   const { token } = JSON.parse(req.body);
if (!token) {
    return res.status(403).json({ msg: "Forbidden" });
 }
 const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET, {
  apiVersion: "2020-08-27",
});
try {
 const customers = await stripe.customers.list(); // returns all customers sorted by createdDate
  res.status(200).json(customers);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.status(500).json({ error: true });
}
 }
}
```

POST:

```
const response = await fetch("/api/get-all-customers", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});
```

This hasn't worked for me - I get this:

```
error - TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
```

Anyone able to help identify what I'm missing please?

Comment: Do you get any customers back if you list all of them without the `email` filter? That list call should work as long as you have a customer with that exact same email on that Stripe account in test mode (or live mode when you make the call in live). If no customers are returned without the `email` filter, then it sounds like you are on a different account or in a different mode than you think you are.

Comment: I've checked - I don't get any customers back at all, if I use the stripe.customers.list method, with or without the email filter. Is there any way I can tell which mode I'm in, as the dashboard says its test mode? I'm using my Stripe Public/Publishable key, so in theory it should work - is this something I need Stripe to check and advise?

Comment: As long as you are using your secret key that starts with `sk_test_` that is from the same account you should see the same customers that you see in the dashboard. Have you double checked that you see customers at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/customers and that you are using your secret key from https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys ?

Comment: Mmm - I've checked both the `sk_test_` key and the customer details; they are both listed in the account, and are both in the code. I am seeing that account listed as a Guest though - would this make any difference? I've not seen how to trigger getting the test customer to register as an account - I suspect though I'm missing something really obvious though!

Comment: Yes, that is it. Guest customers do not have actual Customer objects associated with them. To have Checkout create Customer objects that you can access via the API, you can pass `customer_creation='always'` when creating your Checkout Sessions https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/guest-customers

Comment: I've just tried adding it into my `stripe.sessions.create()` function and it's worked - this is brilliant: thankyou! I've spent hours looking for this fix - adding it now returns values as I need.

For anyone who wants to add this setting - it will be in 
```
stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
     ...
    customer_creation: "if_required" | customer_creation: "always"
  });
```
You can use either example, depending on whether you want to force creation, or have it only when needed. I had to find that value in SO - not sure I've seen it anywhere in the Stripe docs...at least not yet!